# How to control AlertDialog

Tags: android, onclick, android-alertdialog

I have created an app which includes popups of different dialogs.

**Here is my code:**

```java
if (lDiffFromToday >= 0 && lDiffFromToday <= DeclareVariable.CYCLE_MAX_LENGTH)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alrtStartMonitoring = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alrtStartMonitoring.setTitle("              Start Monitoring");
    alrtStartMonitoring.setMessage("Set start date of cycle as"+" "+sdFormatter.format(dtSelDate));
    alrtStartMonitoring.setPositiveButton("Yes", this);
    AlertDialog alert = alrtStartMonitoring.create();
    alert.show();
}   
else if (dtSelDate.getTime()> dtStartDate.getTime() && dtSelDate.getTime() <= currentDate.getTime() && !bCycleStopped)
{
    long lDiffFromStart =dtSelDate.getTime()-dtStartDate.getTime();
    lDiffFromStart=lDiffFromStart/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    if (lDiffFromStart >= DeclareVariable.CYCLE_MIN_LENGTH)
    {
        bActionOk = true;
        AlertDialog.Builder alrtStartMonitoring = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alrtStartMonitoring.setTitle("              Confirm New Cycle");
        alrtStartMonitoring.setMessage("Set start date of cycle as" + " " + sdFormatter.format(dtSelDate));
        alrtStartMonitoring.setPositiveButton("Yes", this);
        AlertDialog alert = alrtStartMonitoring.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}

// ...

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
{
    CycleManager.getSingletonObject().setHistoryDate(dtSelDate);
    int iStopStartCount = CycleManager.getSingletonObject().getStopStartCount();                
    if(iStopStartCount>0)
        CycleManager.getSingletonObject().setStopStartDate(dtSelDate, iStopStartCount);
    displayDay();
}
```

Now my question is that for each dialog I need different `onClick` functions but in my case when I write another `onClick` function then there will be conflict. I know by writing the `onClick` function inside each dialog may solve the problem but in that case, I have to declare my variables as final so how can I do it by writing `onClick` function outside for every dialog I used.

Comment: Please, format the code correctly.

Comment: sorry for that can you please tell me the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution will be to make the AlertDialog instances members of your class. Then in the OnClick method:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
{
  if (dialog == m_Dialog1)
  {
    // server dialog 1
  }

}
```

Comment: is this correct? If you're implementing the onClick from [DialogInterface.OnClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener.html) then the id is the button id that was pressed.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not checking the Id, but the dialog itself.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you've made the your class to implement the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`

instead of

```
alrtStartMonitoring.setPositiveButton("Yes", this);
```

You can make it this way

```
alrtStartMonitoring.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

}
});
```

and for each one of the `setPositiveButton` you can define the different `onClick` listener

Hope this helps

Comment: yeh that i know but on doing so i have to made my variable final which is not needed..thats why i skip this step

Comment: If you declare them as instance variable, you won't need to have them final.

Comment: yeh you are right but on popup of second dialog when i click on ok it gives an error in the device and the app terminate..\

Answer (score 0):

Why not create your own `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` classes and instantiate them with the appropriate variables from your main class that you don't want to mark as final, but do want them to have access to (inject them effectively). Then you can do

```
FooDialogOnClickListener l1 = new FooDialogOnClickListener(dtSelData, ...);
BarDialogOnClickListener l2 = new BarDialogOnClickListener(iStopStartCount, ...);

if (...) {
    // ...
    alrtStartMonitoring.setPositiveButton("Yes", l1);
} else {
    // ...
    alrtStartMonitoring.setPositiveButton("Yes", l2);
}
```